# Bash script using 'watch' fails. Why?

Tags: bash, scripts

I need to run repeatedly (every 3600 seconds) the following commands from the terminal:

```
if whois abcxyz.com | grep -q 'string'; then
    echo 'Message line 1'
    echo 'Message line 2'
fi
```

I tried using watch, as follows:

```
watch -n 3600 if whois abcxyz.com | grep -q 'string'; then
    echo 'Message line 1'
    echo 'Message line 2'
fi
```

but I get error messages.

Could you please help me make it work?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the also the error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since `watch [options] command` executes `command` using `sh -c` by default, you *can* use it run snippets of shell code directly provided that:

1. you get the quoting right

and

2. your code is sh-compatible i.e. doesn't use any bash/zsh/csh-"isms"

So for example

```
$ watch -n 36 'if whois abcxyz.com | grep -q "string"; then
  echo "Message line 1" | ts
  echo "Message line 2" | ts
fi'
```

Comment: Rather than syntax of `watch [options] command` looking at your example perhaps the syntax should be something like `watch [options] 'command'` to *emphasis* the fact the command needs to be quoted. +1 though for good answer.

Answer (score 9):

`watch` is documented (in `man watch`) as:

```
watch [options] command
```

It wants a simple command, not a whole command expression,
so, you have to wrap your command in a `bash` script, and `watch` that.

For example,

In `$HOME/bin/foo`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if whois abcxyz.com | grep -q 'string'; then
    echo 'Message line 1'
else
    echo 'Message line 2'
fi
```

Then, afer making `foo` executable with `chmod +x $HOME/bin/foo`,

```
watch -n 3600 $HOME/bin/foo
```

Comment: Rather than posting a "Thank You" comment, if my answer worked for you, then Accept my answer.

Comment: Comparing your answer to steeldriver's I'm puzzled why his command required quoting...

Comment: @WinEunuuchs: without quoting, the "outer" shell tries to interpret if/then/fi as keywords, but the syntax is wrong.

Comment: @NickMatteo Up-voting this answer for your comment on the quoting.